# Multiple problems with small school project

Tags: c++

I am required to write a program that calculates an employee's net pay with a base deduction of $45. The program has me enter their name, hours worked, and hourly rate. The program also wants me to have a string (EOFNAME) that I can type in to quit. The calculation for hours worked and net pay works fine but I cannot get it to quit with the string. Also, I am required to have it say at the end "Enter next name or (EOFNAME) to quit" which I've tried but cannot figure out. If you can tell me what to do I'd appreciate it.

Edit: I have modified the code at the bottom for the do while loop. The only thing I need to do now is have it repeat the program by asking for another name. Going to leave off the declared variables and other stuff.

```
// Declare input items
cout << "first name or " << EOFNAME << " to quit ";
cin >> name;
if (name == EOFNAME)
{
    cout << "End of program ";
    return 0;
}
else
{
    cout << "Enter hours worked for " << name << endl;
    cin >> hours;
    cout << "Enter hourly rate for " << name << endl;
    cin >> rate;
    gross = hours * rate;
    net = gross - DEDUCTION;    

}
do
{
    cout << "Net pay for " << name << " is " << net << endl;
    break;
}
while (net > 0);     

{
if (net < 0)
    cout << "Deductions not covered. Net is 0." << endl;

}

return 0;
```

} //end of main

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please add values you input and desired output

Comment: All different inputs work as expected, it gives me the net pay.

Comment: You're missing an else statement inside the last braces

Comment: @Moia Replaced the else-if with else. My problem now is how to enter the next name to keep going. I also don't have a way to type the EOFNAME in to close the program.

Comment: I would suggest to update the code in question too

Comment: @Fizzik little tip: your teacher wants to teach you how to use the `while` and `do-while` loops.

Comment: I note that your code does not contain any loops, though the assignment clearly requies one. Can you put your current program into an endless loop? That is necessary to jduge your level of knowledge of programming. I propose an endless do-while. Or go one step further and use an approprate end condition.

Comment: For EOFNAME you can use the `strcmp()` function found in `strings.h`, also to keep going you can put it in a `do while()` loop, the reason to go with `do while()` is so that you always take the first input to begin with.

Comment: @Yunnosch better a do-while with condition instead of infinite loop with break condition.

Comment: @Moia I think he should go with do-while loop since he just began and do-while loop were made specifically for such cases would be good for him to learn it. Oh, you already added that, my bad.

Comment: @Moia That is what I mean, but making the correct condition is the harder part and I wanted to only see that OP knows loops. An endless is the easiest to make.

Comment: @Yunnosch I did previously have an endless loop but couldn't figure out how to stop it so I switched to the end if and if.

Comment: I think your question got clearer by showing your loop construct. But you (accidentally) broke the possibility to compile the code. Please [edit] again and recreate the [mcve]. Also, please use the information provided here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to fix the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code:

   if (name != EOFNAME)
   {
   //do_something
   }
   if (net > 0)
   ...

So even if name == EOFNAME you only skip the first bracket and programme is still running.
You can use for example

```
if (name == EOFNAME)
{
 cout << "End of program";
 return 0;
}
```

Now if user have write EOFNAME program will show "End of program" and will end. In every other situations it will go to line after if statement.

2. Try after showing some sign or sentence end it with endl; It is then more readable in the console view.
3. Try to always assigned values when you create them like:

   ```
   int net = 0;
   ```

This reduces the risk of a later unexpected operation of the program.

4. To say at the end "Enter next name or (EOFNAME) to quit" you have to put everything in while loop.

   ```
   while (logic value)
   {
   \\ do something many times in loop
   }
   ```

It is doing something in loop as long as the logical value is `true`. So You have to create some logic variable `bool` and chagne it to `false` if user want to end program.

5. Think about checking if user write correct answer. What happend if user will answer "Enter hours worked for " with string by mistake? Your program will end with error.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me stop the program when typing EOFNAME.